# img data: URI invalid

Tags: image, google-chrome, data-uri

The following html page creates an error in the latest version of Chrome which appears to be relatively new:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Test page</title>
</head>


<body id="body" >

<img src="data:image\png;base64,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" border="0">

</body>
</html>
```

The error is: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL. But it looks valid against RFC 2397?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a forward slash instead of a backslash on `data:image\png`.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" border="0">
```